# save image after transformations have been applied with Glide

Tags: android, image, android-glide

I have an app I am working on to help me learn Android programming, and I am stuck. I am loading an image from a firebase storage bucket, then applying effects to that image while loading it with Glide. Now I need to find a way to save that image with the effects applied to it, back to the storage bucket. I know how to upload images and save them to Firebase Storage, my problem is, I can't find a way to save the image after applying effects with Glide. Here is a simple example of what I am doing right now..

```
Glide.with(context).load(photo).apply(bitmapTranformation(new ColorFilterTransformation(Color.argb(100, 150, 0, 150))));
```

That loads the image from Firebase Storage and applies a color filter transformation. Is there any possible way to then save that image with that filter applied? I have tried asking in the github channel for the Glide-Transformations, and I have tried asking in the google group for Glide, but haven't gotten any responses yet. I am really hoping someone knows how to do this. The only thing I can think of if it is not possible it to try to save the filter data in a database then every single time anyone loads that image I would have to re-apply the filter. I can't see that being a good solution though, since eventually I want to be able to apply multiple transformations to an image, and trying to store that info in a database then reconstruct it every time seems like the wrong way to go about this.
I will be more than happy to show more code, or whatever you may need. Thank you for any help, I really appreciate it.
On a side note, if anyone needs to know what library I am using to apply the effects it is here... [Glide Transformations](https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this is helpful to anyone else, it is not possible with the Glide library. The only way to do it is to use the built in android image cache and redraw the image from that, like this:

```
ImageView im = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
im.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
im.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = im.getDrawingCache();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
```

You can then upload to Firebase with

```
reference.putBytes(baos.toByteArray());
```

Hope this is helpful to anyone, took me a while to figure this one out. One more thing, if you are trying to save an image, then replace it, add effect, and save it you need to call "im.destroyDrawingCache()" after you compress the bitmap.